# TypeScript: Extend Express.Session interface with own class

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, npm, express-session

I'm working on a Typescript project with npm packages. I want to add a property to the Express.Session interface.

example Class:

```
class User {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

export = User;
```

New d.ts file for the interface definition (don't want to edit express-session.d.ts):

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface Session {
        user: User
    }
}
```

app.ts

```
import User = require('./User');

function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    req.session.user //I want to use it like this.
}
```

the problem is, that User is not known in de d.ts file. But neither require nor import the User-file fixes that.

How can I add my own class to the session interface?

Comment: You probably can't do that. You can declare to the typescript compiler that the `Session` instance has this user property, but in reality (at run time) that won't be the case. Express will execute your function and they will pass a request which has a session, but this session won't have this user.

Comment: it works if i also implement it as an interface in the d.ts file. But it would be better if I only have to write it once. Or at least class and interface in the same file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but it should be possible to import your interface to the definitions file

```
import { User } from '../models/user';

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Session {
      _user?: User
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just a little late... this question was in my first typescript days and quite clear now  but your answer is correct so I accept it

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the other answer did. @Mr.Smith

Answer (score 59):

May be due to the package version, the answer @Vitalii Zurian provided does not work for me. If you want to extend session data on `req.session` and pass the TSC type checks, you should extend [SessionData](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-session/index.d.ts#L206) interface.

E.g.

`User.ts`:

```
class User {
  name: string = '';
  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
}

export = User;
```

`app.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import User from './User';

declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData {
    user: User;
  }
}

function controller(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
  req.session.user;
}
```

package versions:

```json
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-session": "^1.17.1",
"@types/express-session": "^1.17.3",
"@types/express": "^4.17.11",
"typescript": "^3.9.7"
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the code that worked for me with recent versions of the packages ("express": "^4.17.1", "express-session": "^1.17.2",     "typescript": "^3.6.4").

Comment: very clear and concise with code snippets and .json versions.  thank you.

Comment: Can someone direct me to the correct documentation of the answer.
I read this documentation but got lost halfway through
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Answer (score 2):

For me `types.express-session.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface CustomSessionFields {
        myCustomField: string
    }

    export interface Request {
        session: Session & Partial<SessionData> & CustomSessionFields
    }
}
```

This answer relates with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript/70581089#70581089)

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to set them in the *index.d.ts* as an ambient module declaration that will be merged with Express types this is what I have done:

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface CustomSessionFields {
        myCustomField: string;
    }
    type RequestExpress = import('express-serve-static-core').Request;
    type SessionExpress = import('express-session').Session;
    type SessionDataExpress = import('express-session').SessionData;
    export interface RequestExtended extends RequestExpress {
        session: SessionExpress & Partial<SessionDataExpress> & CustomSessionFields
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I love [Lin Du's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65696437/13804071) answer, It might not work for usecases where you may have different Session type for different requests (one for user facing, one for admin panel, etc. -- In this case the session object is not constant)

I ended up creating CustomRequestHandlers to handle different type of Session types instead.

```
import session from 'express-session';
import { ParamsDictionary } from 'express-serve-static-core';
import { ParsedQs } from 'qs';
import { NextFunction, Request, RequestHandler, Response } from 'express';

interface CustomUserSession extends session.Session {
  user: {
    username: string;
  };
}

interface RequestWithSession<
  P = ParamsDictionary,
  ResBody = any,
  ReqBody = any,
  ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
  LocalsObj extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>,
> extends Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, LocalsObj> {
  session: CustomUserSession;
}

export interface UserReqHandler<
  P = ParamsDictionary,
  ResBody = any,
  ReqBody = any,
  ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
  LocalsObj extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>,
> extends RequestHandler {
  (req: RequestWithSession<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, LocalsObj>, res: Response<ResBody, LocalsObj>, next: NextFunction): void;
}
```

Once this was done I would just use it this way

```
export const handleUserAuth: UserReqHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
   req.session.user = {
      username: 'foo', // No Type errors.
   };
}
```

We can then create multiple Req Handlers based on our requirements.