# How can I declare session types with cookie-session?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-session, cookie-session

I am trying to migrate from express-session to cookie-session because I want client-side sessions. For express session I would just simply write on app.ts:

```
declare module 'express-session' {
  interface SessionData {
    isSuperAdmin: boolean;
    token: string;
    operatorId: number;
    providerId?: number;
  }
}

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET as string,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  })
);
```

This would let me use req.session.isSuperAdmin in typescript. But I don´t know how to do it in cookie-session. I setup cookie-session with:

```
cookieSession({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET as string,
});
```

It works, but I can´t use req.session.isSuperAdmin without first checking that attribute exists. How could I declare session´s type so I don´t have to check for every attribute I want to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Extend Express.Session interface with own class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900537/typescript-extend-express-session-interface-with-own-class)

Comment: @TalRofe almost, saw it before but did not work. Realized I needed to edit Request interface, not Session.

Comment: Please what have you tried with that method