# extend express request object with sequelize model using typescript 2

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, namespaces, sequelize.js

I have [some models](http://ngerakines.me/2016/04/11/sequelize/), such as:

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize'; // !

export interface UserAttributes {
    id?: number;
    email?: string;
    googleToken?: string;
}
export interface UserInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<UserInstance, UserAttributes>, UserAttributes {
}
export interface UserModel extends Sequelize.Model<UserInstance, UserAttributes> {
}

// ... model definition
```

I need use *import* statement to use generic type `Sequelize.Instance<TInstance, TAttributes>`

I wright some middleware to add user instance to request object (or *req.session* object, doesn't metter)

Then I need [typescript to know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript) my new extending, for this I have file *src/_extra.ts* with content:

```
/// <reference path="./models/db.ts" /> -- also does not work
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    oauthClient: Googleapis.auth.OAuth2; // Googleapis is namespace
    user?: UserInstance; // or ContactsProject.Models.UserInstance;
  }
  export interface Session {/* ... some same */}
}
```

I need to import my **UserInstance** type from my model file. Imports break all my *_extra* namespace definitions, inside namespace I can't use imports.
I have tried create namespace *ContactsProject*, but I getting same problem: if I use *imports*, typescript don't see my namespace, if I don't, I cant define my *UserInstance* type.
Sequelize doesn't declare namespaces.

I just want import some generic type in my namespace.

I use typescript Version 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an `import` statement in a file, TypeScript treats it as a module. Therefor any namespace you declare inside it will not be global anymore, but local to that module.

Import your interface, and then wrap the namespace declaration in a `declare global { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks, spent a lot of time figuring out this.