# namespace vs module keywords in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces

I'd like to extend Express' Request interface to include user information.  This is common and has been asked here before, so I've been able to accomplish it with the following:

```
import { IHttpUser } from './user.interface';


declare module "express" {
    export interface Request{
        user?: IHttpUser;
    }
}
```

Great - that works.  Without having to use any imports I can just go req.user wherever I am and I have typing information for it.

From what I understand using `module` is not the recommended way to do this.  I should be using `namespace`.  So I'd like to be able to go:

```
import { IHttpUser } from './user.interface';

declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request{
        user?: IHttpUser;
    }    
}
```

...but I can't because if you have an `import` at the top this won't be picked up as being available globally (I apologize I don't know the correct terminology here).

So what is the "correct" way to do this?  It works like I have it, but since I'm supposed to move to using `namespace` I'd like to learn that way.

Comment: From where did you understand that "using module is not the recommended way to do this"?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html 
near the top: "module X { is equivalent to the now-preferred namespace X {".  If I can just go about my life happily using `module` then great, but then my question becomes - "what did MS mean when they stated the above?"

Comment: But `express` is an external module and so based on this doc this is the right way.  You just augment it.

Comment: OK - I had seen in the answers to other Stackoverflow questions people using the `namespace` keyword to extend express.  For example, maximilianvp's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript/37379159#comment68962811_37379159

Comment: I'm not sure that there's an absolute "correct" way here. But, as I wrote, `express` is an external module, and so in my opinion even when augmenting it you should use the `module` keyword.