# Typescript custom type definition breaks on import class

Tags: typescript, module, interface

I’ve a custom type definition to augment an existing interface (Express `Request` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript/37379159)). Content of `express.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    name: string
  }
}
```

Works fine. But instead of `name` being a string, I need it to be a custom class `MyClass` now. The class definition looks like:

```
export class MyClass {
  first: string;
  last: string;
}
```

I change the interface augmentation to:

```
import { MyClass } from "../routes/myClass";
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    name: MyClass
  }
}
```

Now I get the following error when accessing `req.name`:

```
error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Request'.
```

I’ve found out, that my `express.d.ts` effectively becomes a “module” due to the added `import` statement. Still, its not clear to me how I could overcome my problem.

Comment: When you have a top level import/export statement, the file is an module file and you are not augmenting the global namespace Express anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @unional mentioned in the comment, once you have top-level import or export in a file, top-level scope in a file becomes a module scope, separate from global scope.

To amend global declaration in a module, you have to use [`declare global`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to refer to `Express` in global namespace:

```
import { MyClass } from "../routes/myClass";
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      name: MyClass
    }
  }
}
```