# Typescript interface merging to make return type more specific

Tags: typescript, express, interface

I would like to use a custom type definition to make a return type within the Express API more specific. We’re using `app.set` and `app.get` to keep global objects within our application.

`app.get('foo')` returns a specific class `MyClass`, so I'd like to express this fact using TypeScript in order to avoid having to cast explicitly.

The existing definition for `app.get` in the included `index.d.ts` looks as follows:

```
get: ((name: string) => any) & IRouterMatcher<this>;
```

In my custom type definition I added the following:

```
import { MyClass } from '../MyClass';

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Application {
      get (name: 'foo'): MyClass;
      // also tried this to conform to existing structure:
      // get: ((name: 'foo') => MyClass);
    }
  }
}
```

But in both cases, the return type of `app.get('foo')` is still `any`.

Is it possible to implicitly have the correct type, when doing the following …:

```
let myObject = app.get('foo');
```

… and to avoid having to write:

```
let myObject: MyClass = app.get('foo');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, with current version of [express.js type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/65521da5111aa78198e76a2f190816e5ca9c4023/types/express/index.d.ts) I figured out you can augment `get` function with this code.

*custom.d.ts*:

```
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  export interface IRouterMatcher<T> {
    (name: 'foo'): MyClass;
  }
}
```

---

Explanation:

Unfortunately it's a bit hackish solution because you use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) for seemingly unrelated interface. 
You need to do this because you can't use global `Express` namespace augmentation like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762463/350384) answer:

```
declare namespace Express {  
  export interface Application {
    get(name: 'foo'): MyClass; //doesn't work :(
  }
}
```

because if you'll look closer into typings you'll see that [`get`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bfcedfb51227475be0037a97abb7a18ac2e3f72c/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L900) and `set` methods in `Express.Application` are *overridden* with use of [`extends`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bfcedfb51227475be0037a97abb7a18ac2e3f72c/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L836) keyword.

```
export interface Application extends IRouter, Express.Application {
  ...
  set(setting: string, val: any): Application;
  get: ((name: string) => any) & IRouterMatcher<this>;
  ...
}
```

also you can't augment `get` and `set` methods because declaration merging doesn't work if you change the type of property.

```
declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  export interface Application {
    get: ((name: string) => any) &
      IRouterMatcher<this> &
      ((name: 'foo') => MyClass);
      //Error: 'Error: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. :(
  }
}
```

I think a cleaner solution would be to change [DefinitelyTyped typing](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express-serve-static-core). It could work similar to how augmenting of `Request` object is done in [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762463/350384) mentioned question (`get` signature need to be expressed as interface that could be merged with your custom defined types)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and suggestions -- very helpful!