# Typesafe Express Middleware and Routes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

im currently working on a express application that uses typescript. Im currently working on a Authentication Middleware and was wondering if you can make the Middlewares typesafe in a way:

```
authenticateJwt = (
  req: RequestWithToken,
  res: Response,
  next: () => void
) => {
// Append the decoded req.token to the req header so we can use it internally
const token = req.token;

// @ts-ignore
this.verifyJwt(token)
  .then((decoded: Token) => {
    req.token = decoded;
    next();
  })
  .catch(() => res.status(401).send('Unauthorized'));
};
```

now in my routes.ts:

```
router.get(
  '/me',
  // @ts-ignore
  jwtService.authenticateJwt,
  userController.getProfileFromUser
);
```

I have to write // @ts-ignore because it says that `'(req: RequestWithToken, res: Response, next: () => void) => void` is not of type `RequestHandlerParams`

definition of `RequestWithToken`:

```
export interface RequestWithToken extends Request {
  token: Token;
}
export interface Token {
  username: string;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a `custom.d.ts`
and overwrite the `Request` Interface of `express` and `express-serve-static-core`

```
declare module 'express' {
  interface Request {
    token: Token;
  }
}

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
    interface Request {
        token: Token;
    }
}
```

this way both the `RequestHandlerParams`(useually your controller) and `RequestHandler`(useually your Middleware) are getting your new `Request` Interface.

then add it to the `files` section of your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"files": [
    "src/custom.d.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
const token = req.token as Token;
```

Comment: If I use `req: Request` and what you have wrote then it says that `req.token` doesnt exist on type `Request`

Comment: @MichelVorwieger I forgot, you also need to retype your Request interface as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript

Comment: it now works in my middleware but the express Router still complains that `(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) => void` is not of type RequestHandlerParams

Comment: I fixed it by also overwritting the `Request` object from `express-serve-static-core`

Comment: @MichelVorwieger, I'm glad that you resolved it. I would still request you to answer your own question for this thread and not just leave a comment on my answer. This will help other fellows as well.