# Typescript augmentation with fluent API

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some express module augmentations.  My intention is to be able to do:

```
request.message('Hello').status(400).json({});
```

The `status` and `json` functions are part of the express `Response` object.  These functions return the `Response` object they were called on to allow chaining (a.k.a a fluent API).

I wish to add my own `message` function to do much the same.  My augmentation looks like so:

```
import { SomeType } from '...';

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Response {
            // This works.  
            getSomeType(): SomeType;

            // This does not.  Typescript thinks the object returned here has ONLY the getSomeType/message functions on it
            message(str: string): Response; 
        }
    }
```

I've tried variations of

```
message(str: string): Express.Response
```

And

```
message(str: string): Response & Express.Response
```

This made no difference.  As before: Typescript thinks the object returned here has ONLY the getSomeType/message functions on it

Comment: Express isn't a global. You are therefore doing it wrong

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not so sure.  It's a bit of black magic to be sure, but something about the `imports` I need requires this.   After much googling I found the reason for this (Not that I can remember what it was).

If I change to `declare module 'express' { .... }` none of my augmentations work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution.  I needed to import express into my type augmentation, and make my augmentation return `express.Response`:

```
import { SomeType } from '...';
import express from 'express';

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Response { 
        getSomeType(): SomeType;
        message(str: string): express.Response; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you write like this it will be work:

```
import { SomeType } from '...';

declare namespace Express {
  export interface Response {
      getSomeType(): SomeType;
      message(str: string): Response; 
  }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript) was similar question

Comment: Alas, doing this breaks all my augmentations for express.  It's interesting reading the different answers for that thread (I've seen it before)...you see that they all have comments saying "X didn't work for me, I had to do Y".   

The only thing (so far) to work for me is what I posted... at least until this issue :)

Comment: I have the following (relating to express):

`"@types/express": "^4.16.1",` &
`"@types/express-session": "^1.15.12",`

Running typescript `3.3.3333`

Comment: One more question: is this declaration in `d.ts` file or `ts` file?

Comment: It's in a file named `express.d.ts`