# Overwrite `any` in TypeScript when merging interfaces

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm using Express and I'm trying to explicitly define `res.locals`. In the @types/express package, Express.Response.locals is `any`, so I can't seem to overwrite it:

types/express/index.d.ts:

```js
declare namespace Express {
  interface Response {
    locals: {
      myVar: number
    }
  }
}
```

My Middleware:

```js
import * as express from 'express'

function middleware(
  req: express.Request, 
  res: express.Response, 
  next: express.nextFunction
) {
  res.locals.myVar = '10' // I want this to throw a compiler error
  next()
}
```

I want my wrong assignment of `res.locals.myVar` to error, but `res.locals` is still `any` according to my autocompletion.

How can I remove `any` and completely replace it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recently ran into this issue and managed to resolve it by creating an `index.d.ts` in my src folder to overwrite res.locals, my implementation looked like this:

```js
// src/index.d.ts
import 'express';

interface Locals {
  message?: string;
}

declare module 'express' {
  export interface Response  {
    locals: Locals;
  }
}
```

Make sure you also have it included in your tsconfig.json, e.g

```json
// somewhere in your tsconfig.json
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
```

You would use the interface just as you would normally

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export const handler = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  // should be typed
  res.locals.message = 'hello'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Faris, thanks for the answer. I tried it, but with the provided solutions all other types of 'express' are gone. How did you resolve this?

Comment: Hey @natterstefan, make sure you import express at the top of the `index.d.ts`

Comment: Hey @Faris, thanks for the quick response. Can you update and complete the example above, please? Even importing `express` does not resolve it. Maybe you can also add an example usage, eg. `const handler: Express.Handler = (req, res, next) => { ... }`. `res` should then have correct typings, right? Thank you!

Comment: Hey @natterstefan I added some extra stuff that might help.

Comment: Thank you @Faris, worked for me now. Do you also know how to extend `Express.Handler ` so I do not need to add `res: Response`, but still be able to use the custom Response interface?. Edit: Maybe you can link to this resource as well in your answer -> https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L17-L25

Comment: I think this answer is now obsolete. Here's what worked for me (express `4.16.1`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/55718334/3670829

Comment: Also didn't work for me in express 4.17

Comment: Working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/75546820/5043802

Answer (score 3):

The current accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509904/5043802) is outdated and broken. The new solution is to add the following to a `*.d.ts` file in the project like below:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // All your typescript compiler options
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*", "types/*.ts"],
}
```

Then create a `locals.d.ts` inside your *types* folder and add all your custom properties. **Be sure to provide the correct path of the *types* folder**. In my include option, my *types* are in the root directory of the project.

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Locals {
      shopify: { session: Session }
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b986359dc0a8a2108b777c3eb7d3d51909408631/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L16).

Comment: this works really nicely

Comment: @elnygren This still lets you put anything on the interface w/o it caring. Do you know how to make it so locals is only what you specify? In this example only shopify we be on the locals and if you tried to write something else it would error out.

Comment: @topched Just make an interface and export it. Then import it anywhere where you want to use it locally. There are many other solutions too. This is the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to override any using interface merging. You can so some surgery on the type and replace the type using mapped and conditional types:

```
import * as express from 'express'

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

type MyResponse = Omit<express.Response, "locals"> & { 
  locals: {
    myVar: number
  }
}
function middleware(
  req: express.Request, 
  res: MyResponse, 
  next: express.NextFunction
) {
  res.locals.myVar = '10' // error now
  next()
}
```

Comment: This throws `Type '(request: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>, response: MyResponse) => Promise<Response<any> | undefined>' is missing the following properties from type 'Application': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 61 more.` for me.  I'm using express `4.17`.