# How to do declaration merging for `express.Response` correctly with type inference

Tags: typescript, express, type-inference

I'm trying to alter the declaration of `Response.locals` to achieve an extra bit of type safety. Following [the answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57509904/199201) I added the following `index.d.ts` to my project:

```
import * as express from "express";

interface Locals {
  someData: string
}

declare module "express" {
  export interface Response {
    locals: Locals;
  }
}
```

This works quite well when used as follows:

```
app.post("/somePath", (req, res: express.Response) => {
  // res.locals has type `Locals` here
});
```

But if I omit to explicitly state the type of `res`, the compiler seems to infer a different type for `Response`, where `Response.locals` is of type `any` again

```
app.post("/somePath", (req, res) => {
  // oops, res.locals has type `any` here
});
```

leaving all the room for typos (say `somedata` instead of `someData`) I initially wanted to avoid by using Typescript.

What's wrong with my augmentaion of the `Response` interface?

Comment: Solution can be found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75546820/5043802