# How to override external TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-typings

I am using [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) in a TypeScript project. [The DefinitelyTyped type definition for passport](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/passport/index.d.ts) overrides the Express request to include the `user` property. But it defines the user as being an empty interface:

`index.d.ts`

```js
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        ...
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
        interface User {}

        interface Request {
            ...
            user?: User;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However throughout my application I want `req.user` to be this type interface:

```js
interface User {
    id: number
    username: string,
    profilePicture: string,
    name: string
}
```

I am tired of writing `req.user as User | null` throughout my application. I could override the interface definition in the definition file directly but this seems bad practise modifying a file in `node_modules` that will likely get overwritten if I update the type module.

Is there a way to write a definition file in my src folder that overrides `Express.User`? I have tried myself copying and amending the definition file to my src directory but it says

`Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations`

Without `declare global` tsc still treats `req.user` as being of an empty interface.

What configuration do I have to include in `tsconfig.json` to then pickup this override?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript)

Answer (score 11):

Interface declarations in the same scope are merged. That is to say, the following

```
interface A {
  name: string;
}

interface A {
  id: number;
}
```

declares a single interface, namely `A`, with two properties, `name` and `id`.

Therefore, simply use the same technique used by passport to adjust the types.

My convention is to create an augmentations file in the root of my project when I want to augment the type declarations of any dependencies such as express.

**augmentations.d.ts**

```
// ensure file is parsed as a module
export {}

// access the global scope inside our module
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    // introduce another declaration of interface Express.User which will merge with any others
    interface User {
      id: number,
      username: string,
      profilePicture: string,
      name: string
    }
  }
}
```