# How do I properly share context using express and typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, dependency-injection

I'd like to expose a value to all request handlers using express & typescript. I'd like to be able to "inject" this value from a middleware (or some other way), the point is that it should be easy to mock it in case I need to.

I came up with this solution:

```
// The context type, I'd like to be able to inject this using the middleware below. 
// In a real scenario think of this like a database connection, etc.
type RequestContext = {
  foo: string
}

// The type enriching the Request type with the context field
type HasContext = {
  context: RequestContext
}

// Middleware attaching the context to the request
const contextMiddleware =
  (context: RequestContext) => 
  (req: Request & Partial<HasContext>, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    req.context = context
    next()
  }


// Now an actual route using the extra type
const mainRoute = express.Router().get('/test', (req: Request & HasContext, res) => {
  res.json({ context: req.context })
})

// Adding the middlewares and listen
app.use(contextMiddleware({ foo: 'bar' }))
app.use(mainRoute)

app.listen(8000)
```

My questions:

- Is this the intended way of doing this using express? I scouted the API but couldn't find a better solution
- The extra data is attached to the request. Is there any other way that does this without mutating the request or response itself?
- The type `Request & HasContext` has to be defined in each request that uses this context. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can define a custom type for `Request & HasContext` somewhere and import it

Comment: @Phix I know, not really the point of the question. Still for each request handler I have to use the custom type.

Comment: See this question and the answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/58787934/1915893. It shows how you can augment the types in the express package based

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overwrite the express `Request` interface to include your `context` property. This way you don't have to specify the type anywhere. It will also keep all the other properties that `Request` normally has.

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      context: RequestContext 
    }
  }
}
```

I would recommend not using the `Request` object to store information. Express recommends the use of the [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) property.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that's what I was looking for, response.locals it is then.