# extends express request type in typescript

Tags: typescript, express, types, request, extend

**Duplicated:** [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript/51050139)

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import * as uuid from 'uuid';
```

I'm using typescript 3.6.4. I'm extending the express.Request type because I want to add the id field:

```
interface request extends Express.Request {
    id: string
}
```

If I create a post method with a middleware that sets the id:

```
router.post('/orders', (req: request, _res: express.Response, next) => {req.id = uuid.v1(); next();}, async function (req: request, res: express.Response) {
...
});
```

**But I'm getting an error in req: request**

tscongif.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom", 
      "es2017", 
      "esnext.asynciterable"
   ],
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,                 
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,              
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*", "./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are looking for [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

you are able to merge interfaces.
declare in global.d.ts your interface and ts will merge it.

```
declare global {
  declare module 'express' {
    export interface Request {
      id: string;
    }
  }
}
```

and than you are able to use it anywhere in your app

```
const id = Express.request.id;
const anythingElseFromRequestInterface = Express.request.baseUrl;
```

Comment: Why would I do this as opposed to extending the Express Request interface?

Comment: imagine express.use((req: Request) => {req.id}) and you do not need to importing custom interface and extending it here. it will be already everywhere

Comment: I get "Ambient modules cannot be nested in other modules or namespaces." on the second declare. I think it should be: `declare global {  namespace Express { export interface Request { .. } } }` instead!? Also where to store `global.d.ts` file?

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me!

```js
declare module "express" {
  interface Request {
    id: string
  }
}
```

Comment: And what about: `declare global {  namespace Express { export interface Request { .. } }  }`?