# Extending express object using Declaration merging failing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add some properties to the Express/Request object, and everything seems fine but when I try to compile with tsc I get this error: `error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.`

I've tried all the answers found in this post [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript/40762463#40762463), but none of them seem to work for me.

In my root folder I created this:

```js
@types/express/index.d.ts

declare module Express {
  export interface Request {
    id: number
    user_spotify_id: string
    access_token: string
    refresh_token: string
  }
}
```

I also added the types folder to the tsconfig.json file:

```
"typeRoots": ["@types", "node_modules/@types"]
```

This is my callback function for the controller:

```js
async getPlaylists(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { id } = req
    const query = `SELECT * FROM playlist
                    WHERE user_id = $1`
    const { rows: playlists }: { rows: IPlaylistAll[] } = await db.query(query, [id])
    return res.json(playlists[0])
  },
```

I am able to get the id from the request object, and it even says the type is number, but when compiling I get the error I mentioned before.

Answer (score -1):

Look, I was with this problem, I managed to solve it by changing the `--transpileOnly` flag to `--transpile-only` in package.json, check the version you are using of TypeScript, mine is 3.9.6.

And it was not necessary to configure tsconfig.json for min.