# Access an object with express request object in typescript/ javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, request

I have to use an object in all the functions the request in traveling to. I tried using:
`Object.assign(req, {obj});`

But I am unable to retrieve it using `req.obj`.
This gives error `Property 'obj' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.`

I tried setting it in request headers, but when I am fetching that object in other function it is being converted to string | string[].

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you post the complete code where you're facing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript