# Namespace not used from referenced project

Tags: typescript, express

I am using TypeScript for a microservice-oriented monorepo project with directory structure:

```
- root
  - backend
    - shared-files
      -src...
      - tsconfig.json
    - microservice1
      -src...
      - tsconfig.json
    - microservice2
      -src...
      - tsconfig.json
...
```

In order to enrich the Request interface I'm using the accepted answer from [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript), namely I create a file `@types/express/index.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    extraAttribute: string;
  }
}
```

This solution works well for me, however I want this interface (along with other functionalities) to be available in different microservices.

I set up project reference using `shared-files` as referenced. I can use types from `shared-files` with no problems, however that `declare namespace`/`export interface` seem not to be taking effect, and I get `Property 'extraAttribute' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'` on build.

tsconfig files for reference:

`microservice1/tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {"@shared-files/*": ["../../shared-files/src/*"]},
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "../shared-files/src/@types", "./src/@types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  
    "skipLibCheck": true,                   
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../shared-files"}
  ]
}
```

`shared-files/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
     "declaration": true,
     "declarationMap": true,
     "outDir": "./build",
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/@types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "references": []
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not, resorted to duplicating the code for all microservices.