# How to extend type declaration for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-typings

Below question is similar to:
[Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript)

I have pretty much tried all combinations listed in the answers and comments without success. Since that one is over 4 years old, I would like to ask the community anew:

In an Express app, I append `user` property to the request object in the middleware `auth`.

```
// index.ts
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
.
.
app.get('/test', auth, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send(welcomeScreen(req.user?.client_name || ''))
})
```

I get an error:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'
```

That is expected. Thus, I want to extend the type definition of the `express.Request` object to accept my `user` property, supposedly in a custom `d.ts` file.
But no matter how I try to go about it, I still get the same error.
What should be the contents of the d.ts file exactly? My best shot so far is:

```
// custom.d.ts
namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        user?: {}
    }
}
```

After this was added, the `user` property is recognised in the IDE:

```
(property) Express.Request.user?: {} | undefined
```

But I still get the same compile time error.
Do I need to change the `tsconfig` as well? Thanks!

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./compiled",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "typeRoots": ["./types"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,       "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript)

Comment: Can you share the ts configuration file?

Comment: "But I still get the same runtime error."  you mean compile time error? And try without specifying typeRoots - just include it among the glob of tsconfig.json's "include"?

Comment: I corrected the question, thank you. This is what you mean?```"include": ["./types"]```, it don't seem to work

Comment: `"include": "src"` folder or leave it off altogether if your index.ts is just in the project root?  I don't think you should have to specify `typeRoots` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for our team:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
...
    "typeRoots": [
      "@types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
...
  }
}
```

```
// @types/express/index.d.ts
export { }

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user?: {}
        }
    }
}
```

Finally use it as intended:

```
// src/index.ts
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
...
app.get('/test', auth, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send(welcomeScreen(req.user))
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one, because there are a lot of variations that produce similar results, but I think this is the correct answer:

Add `@types/express-serve-static-core` and then in an express-more.d.ts file:

```
import { Express } from "express-serve-static-core";

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user?: {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, unfortunately I didn't work. Maybe the cause is somewhere else, not in the d.ts file?

Comment: and you have `import { Request } from "express";` in your index.ts?

Comment: That is correct. I updated the description.