# Express router requests with custom expected fields

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-declarations

I am in the process of rewriting my JS-based express app into Typescript. While I was refactoring my router instances, I stumbled upon the following issue:

```
this.router.get('/tenantInfo', (req, res) => {
  res.send(this.getTentantInfo(req.tenant))
})
```

When I want to transform this into Typescript it would look something like this:

```
import express, { Request, Response, Router } from 'express'

this.router.get('/tenantInfo', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send(this.getTentantInfo(req.tenant))
})
```

which leads to an error in `req.tenant` since `Request` does not have this property. I searched Stackoverflow and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762463/7365224), however, I think that this will not lead to a good application structure if I just extend the `Request` interface of express with each and **every additional property** that I will expect in **various places** of my application.

What would be a nice approach to solve this in a clean and maintainable manner?

Comment: Extending the `Request` interface is the way to go. `...if I just extend the Request interface of express with each and every additional property that I will expect in various places of my application`, that's the point of TypeScript!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check for a `tenant` before using it, for example:

```
this.router.get('/tenantInfo', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if(req.tenant){
      res.send(this.getTentantInfo(req.tenant))
  }

  res.send({
     message: "Your error message..."      
  })
})
```

I'm not sure, but test and see if it solves your problem

Comment: This would be the JS solution of the problem in order to prevent runtime issues. But in this case it is the same with the if-clause having the same error as before

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't add much to my comment, but you can also separate the `.d.ts` file to multiple places. Lets say you have this directory structure

```
.
└── src
    ├── tenant
    │   ├── request.d.ts
    │   └── routes.ts
    ├── some
    │   ├── interface.ts
    │   ├── some.d.ts
    │   └── routes.ts
    ├── other
    │   └── ...
    └── stuff
        └── ...
```

In `tenant/request.d.ts`

```
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    tenant?: string;
  }
}
```

---

In `some/interface.ts`

```
export interface Some {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}
```

and in `some/request.d.ts`

```
import { Some } from "./interfaces"; 

declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    some?: Some;
  }
}
```

---

Same goes with `other` and `stuff`...