# Error no overload matches this call( Typescript + Express + JWT)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt

I'm learning typescript and I'm trying to build a middleware function that would use jsonwebtoken to manage the rights of the users.

I've first setup a verify token middleware function and I've created an interface that extends the Request interface of Express in this function. By doing this I'm able to attach a users property on the request object that I can use on the jwt.verify callback function. Everything works fine for this part. I don't get any error

But then, when I add the verify function to my router I get the following
error code in the router ts file:

> No overload matches this call.
> The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(req: IGetUserAuthInfoRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.

When I remove the callback function in the jwt.verify function and I set the req parameter type to Request, the error disappears but it's not the expected behaviour since I'm not able to access anymore the user parameter of the request object.

Here is the code for my verify function:

```
import { RequestHandler, Request, NextFunction,Response } from 'express';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';


interface IGetUserAuthInfoRequest extends Request {
    users: jwt.JwtPayload | undefined // or any other type
  }

// Check if jsonwebtoken is valid
const verify = (req:IGetUserAuthInfoRequest, res:Response, next:NextFunction) =>{
    const authHeader = req.headers.token
    if (authHeader && typeof authHeader === 'string') {
        const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1]

        jwt.verify(token, `${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY}`, (err, users)=> {
            if (err) {res.status(403).json("Token is not valid")}
            req.users = users
            next()
        })
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json("Not authenticated")
    }
}
```

Here is my code for my router where I get the error:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import verify from "../verifyToken";
import { updateUser } from "../controllers/userController";



const router = Router();


router.put("/:id", verify,updateUser)

export default router
```

Finally, I've tried to update the req parameter type in the verify function by setting it to Request like the code below:

```
import { RequestHandler, Request, NextFunction,Response } from 'express';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';



// Check if jsonwebtoken is valid
const verify = (req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) =>{
    const authHeader = req.headers.token
    if (authHeader && typeof authHeader === 'string') {
        const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1]

        jwt.verify(token, `${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY}`, (err, users)=> {
            if (err) {res.status(403).json("Token is not valid")}
            req.users = users
            next()
        })
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json("Not authenticated")
    }
}

export default verify
```

When I do this change I get another error on the users property saying:

> Property 'users' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>

I'm really confuse and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in my logic.

Comment: I've found the solution to my problem in this thread basically I needed to extend the express request object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript

Comment: can you please tell me how you fixed above issue.No overload matches this call.

Comment: To solve the problem, I've created custom declaration file named custom.d.ts. In this file, I've declared a new namespace for Express. And I've attached a new property in the request interface of express like the stack overflow link that I,ve added in my comment above. Instead of using "tenant" like the stack overflow solution I've just use the property that I wanted to to access in my request.