# Cannot use RequestHandler interface with custom Request for express typescript

Tags: typescript, express

I am using the request handler interface to design my controllers. Here is an example

```
import { RequestHandler } from "express";

//#region GetLoggedInUserInformation
type GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerParams = {};
type GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerBodyRequest = {};
type GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerResponse = {
  age: number;
  weightKg: number;
  heightCm: number;
  gender: string;
};
type GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerLinkQuery = {};

export const GetLoggedInUserInformationController: RequestHandler<
  GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerParams,
  GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerResponse,
  GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerBodyRequest,
  GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerLinkQuery
> = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // Controller logic
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
//#endregion
```

The problem is that i am passing custom variables to the request during the middleware logic.
Typescript is always throwing an error when i try to read a variable in the req object. Even after declaring global namespace like below :-

```
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    userId : number
  }
}
```

Here is the error when i try to read that variable

```
Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'Request<GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerParams, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerResponse, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerBodyRequest, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerLinkQuery, Record<...>>'.ts(2339)
```

I tried to add custom header interface like this :-

```
export interface ExtendedHeader extends Request {
  userId: number;
}
```

And modify the controller to be like this

```
export const getLoggedInUserInformationController: RequestHandler<
  GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerParams,
  GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerResponse,
  GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerBodyRequest,
  GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerLinkQuery
> = async (req: ExtendedHeader, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userInformation = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id: req.userId },
    });

    res.json({ result: true });
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
};
```

I get an error on the function initiating line with this info

```
const getLoggedInUserInformationController: RequestHandler<GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerParams, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerResponse, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerBodyRequest, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerLinkQuery, Record<...>>
Type '(req: ExtendedHeader, res: Response<GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerResponse, Record<string, any>, number>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerParams, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerResponse, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerBodyRequest, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerLinkQuery, Record<...>>'.
  Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
    Property 'userId' is missing in type 'Request<GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerParams, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerResponse, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerBodyRequest, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerLinkQuery, Record<...>>' but required in type 'ExtendedHeader'.ts(2322)
types.ts(4, 3): 'userId' is declared here.
```

I found the only solution for this is to remove the RequestHandler interface and use the Request Response NextFunction interfaces which coming from express. But there is a lot of controllers that have been designed in that why in our application and i wan't to follow the same procedure with the rest for code readability.

So any idea how i can use RequestHandler interface with extended Request ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript). Note that the accepted answer is obsolete but the other answers should help

Comment: @Phil Thanks Phill, Unfortunately no, The user who asked that question is not using RequestHandler interface, Thus the answers doesn't apply to me. Even though i have tested the mentioned answers. Still throwing the error

Comment: Shouldn't matter. The `RequestHandler` implicitly uses `Request` which if you augment as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47448486/283366), should have the properties you want

Comment: I tested this locally and it works fine for me. I have the `declare global { ... }` from the linked duplicate and `export const getLoggedInUserInformationController: RequestHandler<{}, GetLoggedInUserInformationControllerResponse> = (req, res) => { ... }`

Comment: @Phill I have tested it now. It worked only by declaring the global scope in the app.ts file (the main file which contains all the app.use() functions). When i try to put it in the global.d.ts i get this error ```Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations``` I tried to add ```export {}``` but it's still not working. So the only method to work is to put it inside the app.ts ?

Comment: The above comments are the same response I've found everywhere else, but nowhere have I found someone actually showing how to extend the `Request` interface conditionally so that only handlers that follow certain middlewares have access to the modified request. This is frustrating since I have a set of routes(which use this middleware) that will have additional properties extended on their request objects, but all other routes should still have the unmodified request. I would imagine it would involve changing the `RequestHandler` as mentioned and using that for the type on the handlers likely.