# TypeScript gives a LONG error about "No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error."

Tags: typescript, express

I am writing a user auth middleware based on [Jason Watmore's](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/13/node-mongo-api-with-email-sign-up-verification-authentication-forgot-password#accounts-controller-js) user auth boilerplate.

My expected result is that this code "just works" because it's copied from another project where it does exactly that.

My actual result is that I get this long error message:

```
(alias) authorize(roles?: Role[]): ({
    (req: express.Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: express.Response<...>, next: express.NextFunction): Promise<...>;
    unless: (options: Params) => {
        ...;
    };
} | ((request: RequestWithUser, res: express.Response<...>, next: express.NextFunction) => Promise<...>))[]
import authorize
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ (req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction): Promise<...>; unless: (options: Params) => { ...; }; } | ((request: RequestWithUser, res: Response<...>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<...>))[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '({ (req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction): Promise<...>; unless: (options: Params) => { ...; }; } | ((request: RequestWithUser, res: Response<...>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<...>))[]' is not assignable to type '(ErrorRequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>> | RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<...>>)[]'.
        Type '{ (req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction): Promise<...>; unless: (options: Params) => { ...; }; } | ((request: RequestWithUser, res: Response<...>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<...>)' is not assignable to type 'ErrorRequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>> | RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<...>>'.
          Type '(request: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'ErrorRequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>> | RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<...>>'.
            Type '(request: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'ErrorRequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
              Types of parameters 'res' and 'req' are incompatible.
                Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>': status, sendStatus, links, send, and 53 more.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(163, 5): The last overload is declared here.
No quick fixes available
```

Here is the offending code

```
function authorize(roles: Role[] = []) {
    if (typeof roles === "string") {
        roles = [roles];
    }

    return [
        jwt({
            secret, // authenticate JWT token and attach user to request object (req.user)
            algorithms: ["HS256"],
        }),
// problem is caused here with "RequestWithUser"
        async (request: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            const acctInfo = request.auth;
            if (acctInfo?.acctId === undefined) {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
            }
            request.user = {
                acctId: acctInfo.acctId,
                role: "", // temp to satisfy ts
            };
            const account: Account | null = await acctDAO.getAccountById(acctInfo.acctId);
            if (!account) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
            const refreshTokens = await rtDAO.getAllRefreshTokensForAccount(account.acctId);

            const validRoles = Object.values(Role);
            const acctRole: Role = account.role as Role;
            const rolesFoundOnRequest = roles.length;
            if (rolesFoundOnRequest && !validRoles.includes(acctRole)) {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
            }

            request.user.role = account.role;
            request.user.ownsToken = (token: string) => !!refreshTokens.find((x: any) => x.token === token);
            next();
        },
    ];
}

export default authorize;
```

When I change `RequestWithUser` back to just `Request`, the error goes away, but that doesn't work because then the rest of the middleware will have TS errors about the wrong type being expected. so it has to be this way.

As you can see, `RequestWithUser` is just an Express `Request` extended:

```
export interface RequestWithUser extends Request {
    user?: {
        role: string;
        ownsToken?: Function;
        acctId: number;
    };
    auth?: {
        sub: any;
        acctId: number;
    };
}
```

I don't understand this error message at all. It seems to be saying "express will pass this to `ErrorRequestHandler` and the shapes don't fit" but I'm not clear at all what's up.

edit: so obviously I should tell you where the error appears. The following routes are all examples of where it appears.

```js
 this.router.get("/", authorize([Role.Admin]), this.getAllAccounts);
        this.router.get("/:id", authorize(), this.getAccountById);
        this.router.post("/", authorize([Role.Admin]), createAccountSchema, this.createAccount);
        this.router.put("/:id", authorize(), updateRoleSchema, this.updateAccount);
```

Comment: In the code you've posted this line `request.user.ownsToken = (token: string) => !!refreshTokens.find((x: any) => x.token === token); =` looks like it has a typo. What's that `=` at the end?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the code to reflect the codebase: `request.user.ownsToken = (token: string) => !!refreshTokens.find((x: any) => x.token === token);` No idea how the typo got in there.  I think it happened while I was deleting an irrelevant comment.

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer, but it doesn't look like the contents of the `roles` argument is being used; you could call it with `authorize({length:true})` and it wouldn't matter that no array was passed in (as it just checks whether `roles` has a truthy `length` property). Maybe that's by design, but I'd change it to take a `checkRoles: boolean` argument, rather than giving consumers a false sense of security. But that's me.

Comment: I'll sort that problem out later with tests. Thanks for notifying me. It's not intentional.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I solved the bug you pointed out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `RequestWithUser` is just an Express `Request` extended

Instead of creating a specific interface (even if it extends `Request`), use declaration merging to *augment* the actual `Request` interface itself. See e.g. [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript)

---

The issue is not in the runtime code, but just on the extra typing.

---

The error message itself is indeed misleading, but it is directly caused by the different 1st parameter type.

Because it does not match the usual `Request` type, TypeScript tries to infer a different function overload, and ends up with one that should accept a mix of normal RequestHandler and ErrorRequestHandler... but your functions cannot handle both, hence the error message.

Comment: Hero. This solves my issue in two urgent projects at once.