# How to make the extended attribute required?

Tags: typescript, express

I'm using Express, I set few fields on the `request` object  to use TypeScript feature I created custom interface which extends Express's `Request`  and contains the additional fields.

Those fields are set at the beginning of each request and will never be null, so I don't want to make those fields optional as value will always be there.

```
import { type Request } from 'express'
import { type Context } from '../classes/context.class'

export interface CustomReq extends Request {
  ctx?: Context
}

app.use((req: CustomReq, res: Response, _: NextFunction) => {
  // ..:
});
```

If I make `ctx` required then TypeScript gives this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: CustomReq, _: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathParams'.
```

If it's optional when I access `req.ctx.someField`, it says that `ctx`  may be undefined, so I need to use `req.ctx as Context` but I don't want to do this every time is there any other way?

Comment: It's unclear why you think there's any problem here. If `field2` is a required property in a `B`, then `{ field1: 'test' }` is clearly not a valid `B`. The compiler is telling you exactly the right thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Im using express, i set few fields on the `request` object  to use typescript feature i created custom interface which extends  express's `Request`  and contains the additional fields. 

Those field are set at the begining of each request and will never be null. so I don't want to make those fields optional as value will always be there.

Comment: Then maybe you should give a [mre] _of that_, because from what you've actually posted you've no basis to expect anything different.

Comment: And what exactly does _"starts shouting in the next // line"_ mean?! Think about how you're using that type - given that the callback will be invoked by Express with a vanilla Request, presumably it's telling you you can't assume it will actually receive something different. You should research how to actually extend the existing types, not just randomly create your own interface.

Comment: Do some research, read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37377731/3001761, but the short answer is that this doesn't work because it's completely the wrong approach (your callback cannot be type-safe).

Comment: @jonrsharpe's link is the solution. I arrived at the same: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQzGANsAxsmwIB2cAvnAGZQQhwDkApgB5hR0DOrNAUJ1oa-KjBwAvCjSYceQj3TJ2cAMKEYjeAk5xN5CBABccflGAEA5iLgAiAEbIoFzsW4ATOllks4J9BBvpEGrQJkEDYwZCw6OABRJhZ5dS1EuGMVKDJwyIAlOgBHAFc2NQCkpKwYBn0lAhUGGGKk0k16x0dOQQA6PNY6AAoelhyAGjgAfWGCVQBKEQA+f0SB9rKGcwmAd0VlVR7J+onagH52nYddtrRO7r6B4bG4fZhp4TmErUXl9rIdeoB6H5KAHoHU5AA)

Comment: @hackape looks like you have enough rep to suggest the duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend Express Request object using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377731/extend-express-request-object-using-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics to specify the type of the `body` in the request:

```js
app.use<any, any, { ctx: Context }>((req, resp, next) => {
  req.body.ctx // works fine
})
```