# Adding another property req.user to req, Extending req by custom declaration file does not work in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt

I am a beginner to TypeScript trying to learn by making projects, I am trying to attach another property (user) to the req(Express) in my verifyJWT middleware resulting in error during the compile time as req.user does not exist.

[Github repo](https://github.com/asayushranjansinha/easy-stream-backend)

After reading a lot of posts on internet I tried to solve it using type declaration files attached below but it won't solve. I defined a global declaration in another index.d.ts
**Controller File Below**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

// Models
import UserInstance from '../models/user.model';

// Utilities for handling asynchronous operations
import { asyncHandler } from "../utils/asyncHandler";
import { deleteLocalFile } from '../utils/localFileOperations';

// Cloudinary operations
import { deleteFromCloudinary, uploadOnCloudinary } from "../utils/cloudinary";

// Custom error and response handling utilities
import { ApiError } from "../utils/ApiError";
import { ApiResponse } from "../utils/ApiResponse";
const logoutUser = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const userId = req.user?._id; // error
        if (!userId) {
            throw new ApiError(401, "Unauthorized request")
        }
        await UserInstance.findByIdAndUpdate(
            userId,
            {
                $unset: {
                    refreshToken: 1
                }
            },
            {
                new: true
            }
        );

        const options = {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true
        }

        res
            .status(200)
            .clearCookie("accessToken", options)
            .clearCookie("refreshToken", options)
            .json(new ApiResponse(200, {}, "User logged Out"))
    } catch (error) {

    }
})
```

**Middleware file**

```
import UserInstance from "../models/user.model.js";
import { ApiError } from "../utils/ApiError.js";
import { asyncHandler } from "../utils/asyncHandler.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export const verifyJWT = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, _: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const token = req.cookies?.accessToken || req.header("Authorization")?.replace("Bearer ", "");

        if (!token) {
            throw new ApiError(401, "Unauthorized request");
        }

        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET!) as jwt.JwtPayload;

        const user = await UserInstance
            .findById(decodedToken?._id)
            .select("-password -refreshToken");

        if (!user) {
            throw new ApiError(401, "Invalid Access Token");
        }

        req.user = user // here is the error
        next();
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw new ApiError(401, error?.message || "Invalid access token");
    }
});
```

**ts config**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"], 
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**async handler wrapper**

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

type AsyncFunction = (
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
) => Promise<void>;  

const asyncHandler = (requestHandler: AsyncFunction) => {
    return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        Promise.resolve(requestHandler(req, res, next)).catch((err) => next(err))
    };
};

export { asyncHandler };
```

**Declaration file**

```
import { IUser } from "../../src/interfaces/IUser";

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            user?: IUser;
        }
    }
}
```

**route**

```
  //secured routes
router.route("/logout").post(verifyJWT,  logoutUser)
export default router
```

Comment: I found out the solution that worked for me for express in 2023+[link to the stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66714317/14552572)