express.Request subclass: No overload matches this call
I'm developing a REST API that uses a middleware function to merge an identity object to request object when user is authenticated.
import express from 'express';
import _ from 'lodash';

const authMiddleware = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {

    /*
     *
     *   Authentication logic
     *
     */

  _.merge(req, { identity: user });
}

Hence, upon passing through the middleware, the req object passed down to the handler becomes an express.Request subclass:
interface RequestWithIdentity extends express.Request {
  identity: any[];
}

By doing so, the handler is now able to access identity:
const handler = (req: RequestWithIdentity, res: express.Response) => {

    /*
     *
     *   Handler logic
     *
     */

  const currentUser = req.identity[0];

    /*
     *
     *   Further handler logic
     *
     */
}

Finally the middleware and handler are used inside of a route:
router.method('/path', authMiddleware, handler);

At this point the error arises:
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '(req: RequestWithIdentity, res: express.Response) =>
Promise<express.Response<any, Record<string, any>>>' is not assignable to parameter of type
'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
Please notice that the code you are seeing is being refactored in order to respect best practices, the current working handler code gets req: express.Request and accesses identity by type casting: (req as RequestWithIdentity).identity[0]

router.method only guarantees that the middleware it calls will get an express.Request, not your RequestWithIdentity. Typically you'd use declaration merging to extend their definition, rather than provide your own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762463/3001761.
